# equivalent of `evalin` that doesn't require an output argument (internally)

Tags: matlab, environment

Background -- I was reading up on accessing shadowed functions, and started playing with `builtin` .  I wrote a little function:

```
function klear(x)
%  go to parent environment...
evalin('base', builtin('clear','x')) ;  
end
```

This throws the error:

```
Error using clear
Too many output arguments.
```

I think this happens because `evalin` demands an output from whatever it's being fed, but `clear` is one of the functions which has no return value.
So two questions: am I interpreting this correctly, and if so, is there an alternative function that allows me to execute a function in the parent environment (that doesn't require an output)?

Note: I'm fully aware of the arguments against trying to access shadowed funcs (or rather, to avoid naming functions in a way that overload base funcs, etc).  This is primarily a question to help me learn what can and can't be done in MATLAB.

#### Note 2

My original goal was to write an overload function that would require an input argument, to avoid the malware-ish behavior of `clear`, which defaults to deleting everything.  In  Q&D pseudocode,

```
function clear(x)
if ~exist('x','var') return
execute_in_base_env(builtin(clear(x)))
end
```

Comment: There is also an argument against using `eval`, `evalin` , `clear` ....

Comment: @rahnema1 but what command-line alternative is there to `clear` and its immediate relatives?

Comment: You usually don't need `clear`. MATLAB automatically clears a variable at the end of the function scope.

Comment: @rahnema1 see edits for explanation

Comment: I don't get why you need to use `clear`. If I am forced to use such constructs I prefer to use `x=[]` instead of `clear('x')` and `isempty(x)` instead of `exist('x')`.

Comment: @rahnema1  if I write `x = []` then the variable `x` still exists in my workspace.  An empty variable is not the same as deleting the variable.

Comment: I think there is a problem in your design that your program depends on the `names` of the variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192053/discussion-between-carl-witthoft-and-rahnema1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple issues with your `clear` override:

- It will always `clear` in the base workspace regardless of where it's called from.
- It doesn't support multiple inputs, which is a common use case for clear.

Instead I'd have it check for whether it was called from the base workspace, and special-case that for your check for whether it's clearing everything. If some function is calling plain `clear` to clear all its variables, that's bad practice, but it's still how that function's logic works, and you don't want to break that. Otherwise it could error, or worse, return incorrect results.

So, something like this:

```matlab
function clear(varargin)
  stk = dbstack;
  if numel(stk) == 1 && (nargin == 0 || ismember('all', varargin))
    fprintf('clear: balking at clearing all vars in base workspace. Nothing cleared.\n');
    return;
  end

  % Check for quoting problems
  for i = 1:numel(varargin)
    if any(varargin{i} == '''')
      error('You have a quote in one of your args. That''s not valid.');
    end
  end
  % Construct a clear() call that works with evalin()
  arg_strs = strcat('''', varargin, '''');
  arg_strs = [{'''clear'''} arg_strs];
  expr = ['builtin(' strjoin(arg_strs, ', '), ')'];
  % Do it
  evalin('caller', expr);
end
```

I hope it goes without saying that this is an atrocious hack that I wouldn't recommend in practice. :)

Comment: Awesome, you went way overboard with this! :) However, `clear` now doesn’t work in the base workspace, but `clear all` still does. And `clear all` is bad practice!

Comment: Cool. Add a check for `ismember('all', varargin)` to the `nargin == 0` check (`nargin == 0 || ismember('all', varargin)`) and you'll cover that case, too.

Comment: I have updated my example function to handle the `clear all` case. I'm still letting `clear classes` through, because I figure if you request that, you really _do_ want everything cleared.

Comment: I do appreciate your help -- I have written similar code after reviewing both answers.  My intent was to have a `clear` function intended for use from the console, and designed to avoid the nasty behavior of `base::clear` without any arguments.

Answer (score 2):

What happens in your code:

```
evalin('base', builtin('clear','x'));
```

is that `builtin` is evaluated in the current context, and because it is used as an argument to `evalin`, it is expected to produce an output. It is exactly the same as:

```
ans = builtin('clear','x');
evalin('base',ans);
```

The error message you see occurs in the first of those two lines of code, not in the second. It is not because of `evalin`, which does support calling statements that don't produce an output argument.

`evalin` requires a string to evaluate. You need to build this string:

```
str = 'builtin(''clear'',''x'')';
evalin('base',ans);
```

(In MATLAB, the quote character is escaped by doubling it.)

You function thus would look like this:

```matlab
function clear(var)
try
    evalin('base',['builtin(''clear'',''',var,''')'])
catch
    % ignore error
end
end
```

(Inserting a string into another string this way is rather awkward, one of the many reasons I don't like `eval` and friends).

It might be better to use `evalin('caller',...)` in this case, so that when you call the new `clear` from within a function, it deletes something in the function's workspace, not the base one. I think `'base'` should only be used from within a GUI that is expected to control variables in the user's workspace, not from a function that could be called anywhere and is expected (by its name in this case) to do something local.

---

There are reasons why this might be genuinely useful, but in general you should try to avoid the use of `clear` just as much as the use of `eval` and friends. `clear` slows down program execution. It is much easier (both on the user and on the MATLAB JIT) to assign an empty array to a variable to remove its contents from memory (as suggested by [rahnema1 in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745035/equivalent-of-evalin-that-doesnt-require-an-output-argument-internally/55746924?noredirect=1#comment98169369_55745035). Your base workspace would not be cluttered with variables if you used `function` more: write functions, not scripts!

Comment: Hi Cris,  I'm one of the strongest advocates for functions over scripts you'll ever find.  What I really hope to do is create an overloaded "clear" function so that I can never accidentally type just `clear` and lose lots of variables.  I often have to load from remote servers (at work) and keeping those vars in workspace saves a lot of time.   I don't intend to embed `clear` in any other function.

Comment: @Carl, I added the last bit of the answer just in the hopes of guiding people that come to this page to the right direction. I'm sure you have a good reason to work the way you do.