# Auto close uifigure upon deletion of handle from workspace

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-app-designer

Say I have a GUI class that creates an `uifigure` (see below). I can create an instance of this class in my workspace:

```
tG = testGUI('hi!');
```

I can close the GUI by calling the `delete` method: `tG.delete()`. Is it also possible to automatically close the GUI when the handle `tG` is cleared from the workspace by e.g.

```
clear tG
```

This would prevent opening many instances of the class when running some script multiple times, while the handle to the GUI is already deleted.

**Update**

- removing the `registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)` call in the constructor first seemed to solve the issue, however this did not work in my real GUI.
- Adding a callback to the button in the test GUI reproduces the issue in my MVCE.

---

```
classdef testGUI < matlab.apps.AppBase

    properties (Access = public)
        % The figure handle used.
        UIFigure
        % app name
        name
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        pushButton
    end

    methods (Access = public)

        function app = testGUI(name)
            %TESTGUI - Constructor for the testGUI class.

            % property management
            app.name = name;

            % create GUI components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            %registerApp(app, app.UIFigure); % removing this does not solve the issue
        end

        function delete(app)
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end

    methods (Access = private)

        function createComponents(app)
            %Create the components of the GUI

            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Name', app.name);
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';

            % some button
            app.pushButton = uibutton(app.UIFigure, 'push');
            app.pushButton.Text = 'This is a button';
            app.pushButton.ButtonPushedFcn = @(src,event) someCallBack(app);
        end

        function someCallBack(app)
            fprintf('this is someCallBack\n')
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I figure out that if you don't call `registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)`, then `clear tG` closes the figure. `registerApp` holds a reference to the object, that prevents deletion.

Comment: @Rotem hmm that did the trick in this MCVE, but not in my real GUI. It's a starting point, I will see what functionalities I can add/remove to make it reproducible. Any idea what changes this behavior?

Comment: @Rotem adding a callback to the button changes the behavior, and the GUI stays open when the handle is deleted. Any other solution?

Comment: I didn't mean removing `registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)` is a solution. Based on the following post: [MATLAB - run object destructor when using 'clear'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236649/matlab-run-object-destructor-when-using-clear), I assumed *"there may be other references to the object lingering"*... The added callback makes it weirder.

Comment: I found a solution by overloading (overriding) `clear` method, based on the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55745035/equivalent-of-evalin-that-doesnt-require-an-output-argument-internally). There are many issues overriding `clear`, and I don't think it's a good idea... Do you want me to post it anyway?

Comment: @Rotem if `clear` can be overloaded only within the scope of this class that would be fine, globally overloading the function, no. Thanks for your effort though!